# Navigation is not working in axios call in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, axios

I am using a Post Request using `axios` in React Native to perform the login user functionality. I am getting the response successfully but after login i am not able to navigate to the home screen. here is my code.

```
axios.post('/wp-json/api/v1/user/do_login', {
        username: username,
        password: password
          })
          .then(function (response) {
              console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data.type));
              if(response.data.type == "success"){
                alert("Login Successfully");
                this.props.navigation.navigate("home");
              }else if(response.data.type == "error"){
                alert("Incorrect Detail");
              }


          })
          .catch(function (error) {
            console.log( JSON.stringify(response));
          });
```

In the above code i am getting response successfully but not getting the next screen. here is i am navigating to next screen ..

```
this.props.navigation.navigate("home");
```

Comment: In which screen, is this code used ?

Comment: this code is using in my login screen and after that i want to navigate towards my home (after successful response). but navigation is not working. @WilliamBridge

Comment: Like @dev007 said, arrow function should work. Or try to set navigation object before using it in axios instruction to avoid using **this.props** in then scope.

```const { navigation } = this.props; 
// ....
```

Please can you try to show us your navigation configuration ?